# Proving statistically hiding for a simple commitment scheme in the ROM

Tags: commitments, random-oracle-model

It is well known that one can construct a simple commitment scheme in the [random oracle model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle) (ROM) by setting
$\mathsf{Commit}(m;r) = H(r||m)$, where $m \in \{0,1\}^k$, $r \in \{0,1\}^{2k}$ and $H: \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^k$ is modelled as a Random Oracle.
My question is: How can I formally prove that this scheme is [statistically hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme#Perfect%2C_statistical%2C_and_computational_hiding)?
Intuitively, the RO is "compressing" and therefore there will be enough random strings $r, r'$ such that a challange commitment $c$ in the hiding experiment can have preimages of the form $r||m_0$ or $r'||m_1$ with similar high probability, so even an unbounded adversary has negligible advantage in the experiment. But that is merely an intuition and not a formal proof. I would be really thankful for some advice on how to prove the statement.

(Additionally I'm wondering if random strings $r$ of length $2k$ are enough to achieve statistically hiding. Maybe one can see in the proof that we need a longer random string.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistical hiding for a commitment is not about the distribution of inputs associated with a given commitment output, but rather the distribution of commitment outputs associated with a given pair of messages.

What you need to show is that for any two fixed messages, the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) between the two distributions of outputs is small. Now, the statistical distance is a metric and so the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) applies. A good choice for the third distribution is the uniform distribution on $2^k$ outputs. The random oracle model means that the total variation of the distribution of outputs for a fixed message has small total variation distance from uniform and so by the triangle inequality, the distribution of outputs for two fixed, distinct messages has small total variation distance.